# Was I silent or did I call?

Tags: riddle

> I am often debated,
> About the sound I have created

> Never standing 
> I always fall

> Was I silent 
> Or did I call?

**What am I?**

Comment: Could down votes be explained please?

Comment: I was trying to figure that out too. I can only guess is some people think its too easy, or too brief with no formatting. I sometimes wonder if people downvote just when they don't like something.

Comment: Here I edited it. I hope this helps. If you don't approve any part of my changes, please undo them.

Comment: Some downvotes are likely due to the fact that some people feel this question may invite speculative answers. I personally feel the correct answer is an obviously correct answer for this riddle, but I can see how before it was marked as correct it could have seemed possible there were other valid answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose I would respond:

> **If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?**

So I suppose I would say you are:

> **The philosophical falling tree**

*Explanation:*

> I am often debated, 
> About the sound I have created

> The question this riddle appears to reference is "a philosophical thought experiment that raises questions regarding observation and perception" ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest#:%7E:text=%22If%20a%20tree%20falls%20in,questions%20regarding%20observation%20and%20perception.))

> Never standing 
> I always fall

> You are the philosophical "falling tree", therefore your philosophical existence is not "standing" but always "falling".

> Was I silent 
> Or did I call?

> The very topic of debate: "does it make a sound?"

**You are:**

> **The falling tree**

Answer (score 4):

I would say you are.

> An echo

Explanation:

I am often debated about the sound I have created.

> Echoes are debated because the complex nature of sound reflections makes them hard to understand.

Never standing I always fall

> Echoes are not a constant steady noise but start loud and fall into the distance getting quieter over time.

Was I silent or did I call?

> If there isn't much for sound to reflect off of echoes can be minimal or almost silent. other times the echoes are reflected and sound like someone is calling back at you.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that it's someone speaking in space/ in a void, since

> In space, because there's no gravity, you can't stand, so you're technically falling

and besides

> In a void, sound can't travel, because it requires a medium to move. So, others won't be able to hear it

Because others can't hear it, well, that makes the question of if you were silent or calling debatable